# Make JQuery Marquee When Text Overflows

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, marquee

I am trying to make a Jquery script that will place marquee tags around text if it overflows outside of the `#box` div. The text is obviously wider than 30px, and the div does hide most of the text. My problem is the marquee effect is not appearing. Here is my full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#box {
    width:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="box">
Overflooooooooooow
</div>

<script>

$(function(){
  $box = $('#box');
  $box.children().each(function(){
    if ($box.width() < $(this).width()) {
      $(this).wrap('<marquee>');
    }
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any help. All help is appreciated.

Comment: _"Note also that like most jQuery methods, .children() does not return text nodes; to get all children including text and comment nodes, use .contents()."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text inside the div is just a text-node, not an element you can get the width of. Just add an inner block-element:

```
<div id="box">
   <div>Overflooooooooooow</div>
</div>
```

Edit:

Sorry, won't work with an inner div, as it inherits the parents width by default. Use a span:

```
<div id="box">
   <span>Overflooooooooooow</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes... I was almost posting an answer, but then you corrected it. The div doesn't work because its a `display:block`. Span, its by default a `display:inline`. If you set the inner div to `display:inline`, it will work as well.